# Cannot separate single click and drag on a network nodes in D3

Tags: svg, d3.js, nodes

I am building a network and I am supposed to drag the node and pinned the node and changed color. I am able to accomplish that. However, I can also do a single click to pin the node and changed color. How am I able to disable single click? picture below show what happened after I do a single click.

true and false indicated if the node is pinned or not and the sequence of function of dragstarted, dragged and dragended.

Please help. Thanks.

[image: image of nodes changed to steelblue color and pinned after single click]

Comment: Can you post your code?